# text detection program demos

Tags: video, conversion, ocr

Do you know any text detection software, from images or videos, available as a demo or video demo? Please give me some links.

**Edit:**
better with some paper and it's realization.

**Edit2:**
I want to implement the text detection algorithm from video or images. I see many papers but it is hard to implement them, because of using neural network or SVM - need training.
Others anyway will take some time, and I wanna know if it is possible to try the method and then to implement if it is ok.

**Edit3:** (from comments)
Sorry for my poor explanation, but what I mean is that I want a special program (source code or paper with source code) that can extract text regions from an image. Or video. And then I can use some OCR engine.

Comment: i tryed it, i didn't find any, youtube is locked.

Comment: ok, your second edit and your comment on Wayne's answer is much clearer.  i've added the comment into the question body as a third edit.

Answer (score 1):

I have trouble understanding the question, but I think you are looking for academic papers on optical character recognition and for software that implements (realizes) it. I found the following links by googling "OCR open source".

- [Open-Source OCR Software](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2007/04/open-source-ocr-software-sponsored-by.html)
- [GOCR](http://jocr.sourceforge.net/)
- [Tesseract OCR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tesseract-ocr/)

Recognizing images in video is harder, judging by the smaller number of links I found. I suggest looking for academic papers using the term Video OCR on [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.ca/schhp?hl=en&as_sdt=2000). I did find one link you may find helpful.

- [Video OCR software](http://www.lienhart.de/Source_Code/source_code.html)

Good luck with your research.

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry for my poor explanation,
but what I mean is that I want a special program (source code or paper with source code) that can extract text regions from an image. Or video. 
And then I can use some OCR engine.